# Is the expectation of a (conditional) random variable a number? a still random variable?

Tags: random-variables

Let $X$ and $Y$ be continuous random variables, while $N$ be a discrete random variable.

---

The math assistant said that 4 is the answer for the problem that $\mathbb{E}(X|Y)$ is

1. a number.
2. a discrete random variable.
3. a continuous random variable.
4. not determined due to the lack of information.

   - Since if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $X$ is a number. Otherwise, $X$ is a continuous random variable.

---

I agree the above answer and the reason.
However, I do not understand why the answer is 2 for the following problem that $\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X|Y,N)|N)$ is

1. a number.
2. a discrete random variable.
3. a continuous random variable.
4. not determined due to the lack of information.

---

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: **Hint:** [Recall](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95947/a-generalization-of-the-law-of-iterated-expectations) that $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y,N]\mid N] = \mathbb{E}[X\mid N]$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth If so, the answer of the second problem should be 4 like the first question, shouldn’t it?

Comment: In this case, since $N$ is discrete, $\Bbb{E}[X\mid N]$ would be discrete too (which incorporates the possibility of being a constant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E(X|Z)$ ls always of the form $f(Z)$ for some measurable function $f: \mathbb R  \to \mathbb R$. Hence the conditional probability above is of the form $f(N)$ and this can take only countable number of values.

Comment: I am wondering if $/mathbb{E}(/mathbb{E}(X|Y,N)|N)$X$ is a number if $X$ is independent of both $Y$ and $N$, isn’t it??

Comment: It could be a number. But the point is the conditional probability can take at most countably many values, so it is  a discrete random variable. @Danny_Kim

Comment: If so, why the answer of the first question is not 2 but 4?

Comment: If you say that the answer is 2) you are saying that $E(X|Y)$ **must be** be discrete. There are examples where is is not, so 2) is not the right option for the first question. In the second question the conditional probability **is necessarily** discrete , so 2) is the right option. @Danny_Kim

Comment: I am really sorry. I mean number 3. Not 2. That is, as the same principle, the answer of the first question is 3.

Comment: It is already mentioned  that in the first question $E(X|Y)$ can be a constant and it can also be a continuous random variable. So 2) and 3) are both false in the first question.